# Probabilty Models and distribution techniques

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Coliform bacteria are distributed randomly and uniformly throughout river water at the average concentration of one per twenty cubic centimeters of water.

Part (c)

In testing for the concentration (average number per unit volume) of bacteria it is possible to determine cheaply whether a sample has any (i.e. 1 or more) bacteria present or not.

Suppose the average concentration of bacteria in a body of water is λ per cubic centimeter. If 10 independent water samples of 10 c.c. each are tested, let the random variable Y be the number of samples with no bacteria. Find P (Y = y).

$P(Y=y) =$ $10\choose y$$(e^{-10λ})^y(1-e^{-10λ})^{10-y}$

Part (d)

Suppose that of 10 samples, 3 had no bacteria. Find an estimate for the value of λ

So basically using the equation in part (c), to calculate for part d, I'm guessing i sub $y$ as 3, but how do i get λ?

Comment: Can anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The probability that of the $10$ samples , contain no bacteria is $\frac{3}{10}= 0.3$.

Using Poisson approximation, this probability equals $e^{−10λ}$.

Then $e^{−10λ}= 0.3$.